# htaccess URL redirection - Want to remove a word from URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect some URLs to different URL. For instance

```
http://www.mydomain.com/some-text-2-rss/
http://www.mydomain.com/another-text-rss
http://www.mydomain.com/sample-rss/
http://www.mydomain.com/dummy-content-rss
http://www.mydomain.com/some-folder-1/my-text-rss
http://www.mydomain.com/another-folder/some-text-rss/

TO

http://www.mydomain.com/some-text-2/
http://www.mydomain.com/another-text
http://www.mydomain.com/sample/
http://www.mydomain.com/dummy-content
http://www.mydomain.com/some-folder-1/my-text
http://www.mydomain.com/another-folder/some-text/
```

i.e if any URL's ending is '-rss' or '-rss/', i want to remove '-rss' from the URL.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you done so far, and how well has it worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+?)-rss(/?)$ /$1$2 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Nothing is happening with this rule and i am searching for REDIRECTION not Rewriting. When i am browsing http://www.mydomain.com/dummy-content-rss it should redirect to http://www.mydomain.com/dummy-content. i.e -rss should not be in address bar.

Comment: Above is indeed **an external redirection** due to the presence of `R` flag. Make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled and above is in DOCUMENT_ROOT. If you have several other rules in .htaccess then please provide your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your rule is working fine now, i have made a small change in my question i.e it should work even the URL having subdirectory.

Comment: I wish you would have tested my rule with sub directory first :) My original solution will work with any # of sub directories in between and I had tested with all type of those URLs before posting here as a solution.

Comment: Yes i tested this Rule with subdirectory in my local server and it was not working, but it is working fine in server. Thank you very much for you answer.